# How to turn an envelope into a template vai the Docusign API without losing recipients names and email addresses?

Tags: docusignapi

Initial Envelope Recipients [Recipients with specific names / email addresses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHW9a.png)

Example:

```
Oliver Test
oliver.test@test.com
```

API call to transform envelope into template

Post: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx/templates

```
{
    "EnvelopeID": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
    "name": "Basic Example",
    "emailSubject": "Template Subject",
    "envelopeTemplateDefinition": {
      "name": "Template Name",
      "shared": "true",
      "description": "Template Description",
      "recipients": {
        "signers": [
          {
            "name": "Oliver Test",
            "email": "soliver.test@test.com",
            "roleName": "Staff 1"
          }
        ]
      },
      "documents": [
        {
          "documentId": "1",
          "name": "Document Name"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to carry over or set the recipient's name/email/role in the transformation of envelope to template via the api call?

Resulting Template [Recipients with generic name, no email addresses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57sUM.png)

Example:

```
Signer 1
```

Desired Result Example:

```
Staff 1
Oliver Test
oliver.test@test.com
```

Answer (score 0):

The [feature that enables you to take an envelope and make a template](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-create-template-envelope) out of it does not use the recipient details from the envelope.
Instead DocuSign creates placeholder recipients that you fill when you use this template to create envelopes.
By far, [placeholder recipients](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=xry1643227563338&topicId=lsg1578456368117.html&_LANG=enus) are much more useful, as you do not need to hardcode emails and names in your templates.
If you do want to make it fixed recipients, you can make an API call to [modify (PUT) your template's recipients](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/templates/templaterecipients/update/) in it in that way.